# How to use Golang custom scanner string literals and expand memory to load entire file into memory?

Tags: go, string-literals

I have been trying to figure out how to implement what I originally thought would be a simple program.
I have a text file of quotations that are all separated by ‘$$’

I want the program to parse the quotation file and randomly select 3 quotes to display and standard output.

There are 1022 quotes in the file.

**When I attempt to split the file I get this error:
 missing '**

I can’t seem to figure out how to assign $$ with a string literal, I keep getting:
    missing '

This is the custom scanner:

```
onDollarSign := func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {  
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ { 
        //if data[i] == "$$" {              # this is what I did originally
        //if data[i:i+2] == "$$" {    # (mismatched types []byte and string)
        //if data[i:i+2] == `$$` {    # throws (mismatched types []byte and string)
        // below throws syntax error: unexpected $ AND missing '
        if data[1:i+2] == '$$' {   
            return i + 1, data[:i], nil  
        }  
    }
```

The string literal works fine if I only use one `$`.

For some reason **only 71 quotations are loaded into the quotes slice.**  I'm not sure how to expand. To allow all 1022 quotes to be stored in memory.

I've been having a really difficult time trying to figure out how to do this. this is what I have right now:

```
package main
import (  
    "bufio"  
    "fmt"  
    "log"  
    "math/rand"  
    "os"  
    "time"  
)  

func main() {  
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano()) // Try changing this number!  
    quote_file, err := os.Open("/Users/bryan/Dropbox/quotes_file.txt")  
    if err != nil {  
        log.Fatal(err)  
    }  
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(quote_file)  
    // define split function  
    onDollarSign := func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {  
        for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {  
            if data[i] == '$$' {  
                return i + 1, data[:i], nil  
            }  
        }  
        fmt.Print(data)  
        return 0, data, bufio.ErrFinalToken  
    }  
    scanner.Split(onDollarSign)  
    var quotes []string  

    // I think this will scan the file and append all the parsed quotes into quotes  
    for scanner.Scan() {  
        quotes = append(quotes, scanner.Text())  

    }  
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {  
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)  
    }  
    fmt.Print(len(quotes))  
    fmt.Println("quote 1:", quotes[rand.Intn(len(quotes))])  
    fmt.Println("quote 2:", quotes[rand.Intn(len(quotes))])  
    fmt.Println("quote 3:", quotes[rand.Intn(len(quotes))])  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a scanner if you end up reading the whole file anyway is kind of convoluted. I'd read the whole file and then simply split it into the list of quotes:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Slurp file.
    contents, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/bryan/Dropbox/quotes_file.txt")
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Split the quotes
    separator := []byte("$$") // Convert string to []byte
    quotes := bytes.Split(contents, separator)

    // Select three random quotes and write them to stdout
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            n := rand.Intn(len(quotes))
            quote := quotes[n]

            os.Stdout.Write(quote)
            os.Stdout.Write([]byte{'\n'}) // new line, if necessary
    }
}
```

Using a scanner would make sense if you selected three quotes *before* reading the file; then you can stop reading after you have reached the last quote.

Comment: So Scanner should only be used if you are working with part of the file?  In this case, how would you be able to count the total number of quotes in the file without fully reading the file?

Comment: If you don't know the number of quotes up front you have no choice but to read the whole file. And in that case using a scanner is more complicated than slurping the file and splitting the bytes.

Answer (score 3):

In golang single quote `'` is used for single chars(so called "runes" - internally it is an `int32` with unicode code point), and double quote for strings which can be longer than 1 char:  `"$$"`.

So parser awaits a closing rune chanacter `'` just after the first dollar sign.

Here's a good article: https://blog.golang.org/strings

**UPDATE:** If you want to avoid casting all `data` to string you may check this way:

```
...
   onDollarSign := func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {  
        for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {  
            if data[i] == '$' && data[i+1] == '$' {  /////   <----
                return i + 1, data[:i], nil  
            }  
        }  
        fmt.Print(data)  
        return 0, data, bufio.ErrFinalToken  
    } 
...
```

Comment: I changed do double quote:  cannot convert "$$" to type byte

Comment: I thinnk this is due to comparison `data[i] == '$$'`.  Try to use `data[i:i+1] == "$$"`. Could you pls load the code and some data examples to https://play.golang.org to see it alive?

Comment: My mistake: `data[i:i+2] == "$$"`

Comment: ./quote_generator.go:38: invalid operation: data[i:i + 2] == "$$" (mismatched types []byte and string)

Comment: I'm not sure how to add this file to play.golang.org because of the external quote file. I attempted to create a string with elements separated by $$ and got cannot use quote_file (type string) as type io.Reader in argument to bufio.NewScanner:
 string does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)

Comment: Could you please share this code  with the error on play.golang.org or gist?

Comment: It is easier to help If I have an example of strings. Not all - about 100 is enough. Pls try to define delimiter like this `delimiter := []byte("$$")` then comparison `if reflect.DeepEqual(data[i:i+2], delimiter) ...`   another way is to  cast both `data` and `delimiter` to type `string` and compare with operation above `data[i:i + 2] == "$$" `

Comment: Or `if data[i] =='$' && data[i+1] == '$'`

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your split function based off the stdlib func [bufio.Scanlines](https://golang.org/src/bufio/scan.go?s=11488:11566#L329).

I haven't tested it thoroughly so you should exercise it. Also you should decide how you want to handle whitespace such as the newline at the end of the file.

```
func onDollarSign(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {

    // If we are at the end of the file and there's no more data then we're done
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    // If we are at the end of the file and there IS more data return it
    if atEOF {
        return len(data), data, nil
    }

    // If we find a $ then check if the next rune after is also a $. If so we
    // want to advance past the second $ and return a token up to but not
    // including the first $.
    if i := bytes.IndexByte(data, '$'); i >= 0 {
        if len(data) > i && data[i+1] == '$' {
            return i + 2, data[0:i], nil
        }
    }

    // Request more data.
    return 0, nil, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scanning for quotes (`scanQuotes`) is similar to scanning for lines ([`bufio.ScanLines`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanLines)). For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func dropCRLF(data []byte) []byte {
    if len(data) > 0 && data[len(data)-1] == '\n' {
        data = data[0 : len(data)-1]
        if len(data) > 0 && data[len(data)-1] == '\r' {
            data = data[0 : len(data)-1]
        }
    }
    return data
}

func scanQuotes(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    if atEOF && len(dropCRLF(data)) == 0 {
        return len(data), nil, nil
    }
    sep := []byte("$$")
    if i := bytes.Index(data, sep); i >= 0 {
        return i + len(sep), dropCRLF(data[0:i]), nil
    }
    if atEOF {
        return len(data), dropCRLF(data), nil
    }
    return 0, nil, nil
}

func main() {
    /*
       quote_file, err := os.Open("/Users/bryan/Dropbox/quotes_file.txt")
       if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
       }
    */
    quote_file := strings.NewReader(shakespeare) // test data

    var quotes []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(quote_file)
    scanner.Split(scanQuotes)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        quotes = append(quotes, scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading quotes:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(len(quotes))
    for i, quote := range quotes {
        fmt.Println(i, quote)
    }
}

var shakespeare = `To be, or not to be: that is the question$$All the world‘s a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their exits and their entrances; And one man in his time plays many parts.$$Romeo, Romeo! wherefore art thou Romeo?$$Now is the winter of our discontent$$Is this a dagger which I see before me, the handle toward my hand?$$Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them.$$Cowards die many times before their deaths; the valiant never taste of death but once.$$Full fathom five thy father lies, of his bones are coral made. Those are pearls that were his eyes. Nothing of him that doth fade, but doth suffer a sea-change into something rich and strange.$$A man can die but once.$$How sharper than a serpent’s tooth it is to have a thankless child!` + "\n"
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/zMuWMxXJyQ

Output:

```
10
0 To be, or not to be: that is the question
1 All the world‘s a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their exits and their entrances; And one man in his time plays many parts.
2 Romeo, Romeo! wherefore art thou Romeo?
3 Now is the winter of our discontent
4 Is this a dagger which I see before me, the handle toward my hand?
5 Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them.
6 Cowards die many times before their deaths; the valiant never taste of death but once.
7 Full fathom five thy father lies, of his bones are coral made. Those are pearls that were his eyes. Nothing of him that doth fade, but doth suffer a sea-change into something rich and strange.
8 A man can die but once.
9 How sharper than a serpent’s tooth it is to have a thankless child!
```