# GoLang Get String at Line N in Byte Slice

Tags: string, go, random, byte, slice

In a personal project I am implementing a function that returns a random line from a long file. For it to work I have to create a function that returns a string at line N, a second function that creates a random number between 0 and lines in file. While I was implementing those I figured it may be more efficient to store the data in byte slices by default, rather than storing them in separate files, which have to be read at run time.

Question: How would I go about implementing a function that returns a string at a random line of the `[]byte` representation of my file.

My function for getting a string from a file:

```
func atLine(n int) (s string) {
    f, err := os.Open("./path/to/file")
    if err != nil {
        panic("Could not read file.")
    }
    defer f.Close()
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    for i := 1; ; i++ {
        line, _, err := r.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        if i == n {
            s = string(line[:])
            break
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Additional info:

- Lines are not longer than 50 characters at most
- Lines have no special characters (although a solution handling those is welcome)
- Number of lines in the files is known and so the same can be applied for `[]byte`

Comment: I am not quite sure what it is that you want to change here? The function `atLine`?
Also, why is this too slow, have you profiled the program? What are the result of profiling?

Comment: so, you always read the file every time you want to get just one line? this is obviously slow

Comment: If you really do this multiple times as @srxf asks, opening and reading the file every time, it might be wise to open it once at the beginning, find all line breaks and remember them, then only ever read that range directly from the file in `atLine`. This might be a viable optimization if that is really your bottleneck. Again it is not clear from the question why you think this is not efficient enough.

Comment: Thank you all. Those are valid points. The code I've provided accounts for the data being able to change at run-time, and therefore also involves N of lines checking, which I've omitted. My use case is that I want to have static byte slice declarations of the files in my .go file and read from that instead of from disk.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609805

Comment: Have a look at [github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) if you want to compile a text file into your program.

Comment: @Peter I think you misunderstodd. My question is much simpler, it boils down to the difference between `*File` and `[]byte` and how to use the latter in a specific case.

Comment: "My use case is that I want to have static byte slice declarations of the files in my .go file and read from that instead of from disk." That's exactly what bindata is intended for. The question I linked earlier shows how to select three random lines from a byte slice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dealing with just the question part (and not the sanity of this) - you have a `[]byte` and want to get a specific string line from it - the `bytes.Reader` has no `ReadLine` method which you will have already noticed.

You can pass a bytes reader to `bufio.NewReader`, and gain the `ReadLine` functionality you are trying to access.

```
bytesReader := bytes.NewReader([]byte("test1\ntest2\ntest3\n"))
bufReader := bufio.NewReader(bytesReader)
value1, _, _ := bufReader.ReadLine()
value2, _, _ := bufReader.ReadLine()
value3, _, _ := bufReader.ReadLine()
fmt.Println(string(value1))
fmt.Println(string(value2))
fmt.Println(string(value3))
```

Obviously it is not sensible to ignore the errors, but for the purpose of brevity I do it here.

https://play.golang.org/p/fRQUfmZQke

Results:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

From here, it is straight forward to fit back into your existing code.

Comment: this is probably better, you can just store the the lines to an array of string.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I am very new to go and so was having trouble using `[]byte` with common interfaces, like readers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of fast (in the order of nanoseconds) random access to lines of text as byte data. The data is buffered and indexed in memory.

`lines.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Lines struct {
    data  []byte
    index []int // line start, end pairs for data[start:end]
}

func NewLines(data []byte, nLines int) *Lines {
    bom := []byte{0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF}
    if bytes.HasPrefix(data, bom) {
        data = data[len(bom):]
    }
    lines := Lines{data: data, index: make([]int, 0, 2*nLines)}
    for i := 0; ; {
        j := bytes.IndexByte(lines.data[i:], '\n')
        if j < 0 {
            if len(lines.data[i:]) > 0 {
                lines.index = append(lines.index, i)
                lines.index = append(lines.index, len(lines.data))
            }
            break
        }
        lines.index = append(lines.index, i)
        j += i
        i = j + 1
        if j > 0 && lines.data[j-1] == '\r' {
            j--
        }
        lines.index = append(lines.index, j)
    }
    if len(lines.index) != cap(lines.index) {
        lines.index = append([]int(nil), lines.index...)
    }
    return &lines
}

func (l *Lines) N() int {
    return len(l.index) / 2
}

func (l *Lines) At(n int) (string, error) {
    if 1 > n || n > l.N() {
        err := fmt.Errorf(
            "data has %d lines: at %d out of range",
            l.N(), n,
        )
        return "", err
    }
    m := 2 * (n - 1)
    return string(l.data[l.index[m]:l.index[m+1]]), nil
}

var (
    // The Complete Works of William Shakespeare
    // http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt
    fName  = `/home/peter/shakespeare.pg100.txt`
    nLines = 124787
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }

    lines := NewLines(data, nLines)

    for _, at := range []int{1 - 1, 1, 2, 12, 42, 124754, lines.N(), lines.N() + 1} {
        line, err := lines.At(at)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%d\t%v\n", at, err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%d\t%q\n", at, line)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0       data has 124787 lines: at 0 out of range
1       "The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare, by"
2       "William Shakespeare"
12      "Title: The Complete Works of William Shakespeare"
42      "SHAKESPEARE IS COPYRIGHT 1990-1993 BY WORLD LIBRARY, INC., AND IS"
124754  "http://www.gutenberg.org"
124787  "*** END: FULL LICENSE ***"
124788  data has 124787 lines: at 124788 out of range
```

`lines_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
)

func benchData(b *testing.B) []byte {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fName)
    if err != nil {
        b.Fatal(err)
    }
    return data
}

func BenchmarkNewLines(b *testing.B) {
    data := benchData(b)
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        lines := NewLines(data, nLines)
        _ = lines
    }
}

func BenchmarkLineAt(b *testing.B) {
    data := benchData(b)
    lines := NewLines(data, nLines)
    ats := make([]int, 4*1024)
    ats[0], ats[1] = 1, lines.N()
    rand.Seed(42)
    for i := range ats[2:] {
        ats[2+i] = 1 + rand.Intn(lines.N())
    }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        at := ats[i%len(ats)]
        line, err := lines.At(at)
        if err != nil {
            b.Error(err)
        }
        _ = line
    }
}
```

Output

```
$ go test -bench=. lines.go lines_test.go
BenchmarkNewLines-8       1000   1898347 ns/op     1998898 B/op   2 allocs/op
BenchmarkLineAt-8     50000000        45.1 ns/op        49 B/op   0 allocs/op
```